# dart:html WebSocket vs dart:io WebSocket

Tags: dart, websocket, dart-html

I was looking out for a sample WebSocket implementation on DartPad.

Here's a link to the implementation: [WebSocket Sample](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/cb9b199b1085873de191e32a1dd5ca4f)

However, while trying to implement the same on my local machine, I encountered that Dart has two implementations of the `WebSocket` class.

One is provided in the `dart:io` package and another is provided in `dart:html` package.

Can anyone provide what's the difference between the two and what are the advantages of one over the other?

Answer (score 3):

The one in dart:io is used for standalone app running on Dart VM including Flutter, while the one in dart:html is for Web browsers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no major difference other than some implementation changes in both libraries:

WS in dart:io: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-io/WebSocket-class.html

WS in dart:html: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-html/WebSocket-class.html#constructors

if you see closely both the classes have the same approach in everything except creating a web socket instance.

**dart:io** :

Simple no arg constructor is [deprecated](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-io/WebSocket/WebSocket.html). But has a [factory method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-io/WebSocket/WebSocket.fromUpgradedSocket.html) to create an instance using a `Socket`.

**dart:html** :

Websocket [constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-html/WebSocket/WebSocket.html) takes a `url` string and a list of `protocol` objects.